# Get spring security oauth to access askToLinkOrCreateAccount.gsp

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security

How can you access the askToLinkOrCreateAccount.gsp inherent in the SpringSecurityOAuthController?

I am trying to access the functionality to link oAuth credentials to an existing Grails account as opposed to creating a new one.

- grails 2.4.2
- spring-security-core-2.0-RC4,
- spring-security-oauth-2.0.2
- spring-security-oauth-google-0.1